# how to show video file in mvc when i have a physical path in my table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, video, asp.net-mvc-5

i have physical path of video in my database table how can i show those video files in my mvc view. can anyone give me an idea.

here is my service layer in which i am getting all the values in a list

```
public IEnumerable<Marketing> GetMarketingContents()
        {
            return fDbContext.Marketings.ToList();
        }
```

view model

```
public class ViewModelMarketing
    {

        public List<Marketing> MarketVideo { get; set; }
    }
```

here is my controller in which i am filtering the videos and passing it to the partial view.

```
 public ActionResult MarketingListVideos()
        {

                ViewModelMarketing viewModelMarketing = new ViewModelMarketing();

                var debs = from s in iMarketingService.GetMarketingContents()
                           select s;
                viewModelMarketing.MarketVideo = debs.Where(t => t.MarketingType.Equals("v") && t.Active != false).ToList();
                return PartialView("_GetVideos", viewModelMarketing);
            }
```

here is my partial view named _GetVideos
@model PreFlight.ViewModels.ViewModelMarketing

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MarketVideo)
{
    <div class="list-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video" style="color: black"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5">
                @item.Content
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5">
                @item.Active
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

here is my main view in which i am rendering this partial view

```
@model PreFlight.ViewModels.ViewModelMarketing
<div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="list-group">
                            @Html.Action("MarketingListVideos", "Marketing")
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

now i am getting the list of videos in my view. how can i show it as a video files. can any one help me to get this. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Refer this link may help you to solve your problem  http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui,-layouts,-and-themes/10-working-with-video  and http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-Save-Retrieve-and-Play-MP4-Video-files-with-live-streaming-from-Database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML5 :

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.MarketVideo)
  {
     <div class="list-group">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video" style="color: black"></i>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5">
              @item.Content
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5">
              @item.Active
           </div>
           <video controls="controls">
              <source src="@item.YourVideoPath" type="video/mp4" />
           </video>
        </div>
     </div>
  }
```

And for best pratices you should espeficy the correct extension:

```
<video controls="controls">
              <source src="@item.YourVideoPath" type="video/@item.VideoExtension" />
           </video>
```

Here some referece:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Note: just remember that not all browsers supports the video tag, but a good amount does

Comment: @Teerth did you use this way <video src="~/Media/@item.Content" style="width:100px; height:75px;"> ? the src it's inside the source tag which is inside de video tag , notice the difference ? try using 

<video controls="controls">
              <source src="~/Media/@item.Content"  />
           </video>

the type it's not mandatory